# Share unity context with Android native as gl context

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, android-context

I have problem with my application which use Android native with unity.

My native uses opengl but when I deliver unity context to my own native,
then it stopped with this message,

> E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

I think this error occurs from context deliver,
I just use common source for this process

```
using (activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
{
    activityContext = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
}
NativePlugin = pluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
NativePlugin.Call("setContext", activityContext);
```

In this process, activityContext doesn't have gl properties and error occurs
is it right?

How can I get GLcontext from unity context?
Is there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePluginInterface.html):

> Rendering in Unity can be multithreaded if the platform and number of available CPUs will allow for it. When multithreaded rendering is used, the rendering API commands happen on a thread which is completely separate from the one that runs MonoBehaviour scripts.

You probably have multithreaded rendering turned on, so it might be the case.
You could try to turn it off and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Shaman.
I tried this solution but, now I got another problem.
With that glcontext, My shader doesn't work well.
I will try on it. thank you